# Access MSMQ from C++ (non COM component) code

Tags: c++, runtime-error, msmq

I am new to the concept of MSMQ(Microsoft Message Queues). I had a glimpse of the sample code from [Microsoft's link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and am trying to create a simple MSMQ queue. Here is my full code (mostly from Microsoft's link).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "mq.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "Mqrt.lib")
#include "tchar.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFLEN = 256;


#include <iostream>

HRESULT CreateMSMQQueue(
                        LPWSTR wszPathName, 
                        PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor,
                        LPWSTR wszOutFormatName,
                        DWORD *pdwOutFormatNameLength
                        )
{

  // Define the maximum number of queue properties.
  const int NUMBEROFPROPERTIES = 2;


  // Define a queue property structure and the structures needed to initialize it.
  MQQUEUEPROPS   QueueProps;
  MQPROPVARIANT  aQueuePropVar[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES];
  QUEUEPROPID    aQueuePropId[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES];
  HRESULT        aQueueStatus[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES];
  HRESULT        hr = MQ_OK;


  // Validate the input parameters.
  if (wszPathName == NULL || wszOutFormatName == NULL || pdwOutFormatNameLength == NULL)
  {
    return MQ_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
  }


  // Set queue properties.
  DWORD cPropId = 0;
  aQueuePropId[cPropId] = PROPID_Q_PATHNAME;
  aQueuePropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_LPWSTR;
  aQueuePropVar[cPropId].pwszVal = wszPathName;
  cPropId++;

  WCHAR wszLabel[MQ_MAX_Q_LABEL_LEN] = L"Test Queue";
  aQueuePropId[cPropId] = PROPID_Q_LABEL;
  aQueuePropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_LPWSTR;
  aQueuePropVar[cPropId].pwszVal = wszLabel;
  cPropId++;


  // Initialize the MQQUEUEPROPS structure.
  QueueProps.cProp = cPropId;               // Number of properties
  QueueProps.aPropID = aQueuePropId;        // IDs of the queue properties
  QueueProps.aPropVar = aQueuePropVar;      // Values of the queue properties
  QueueProps.aStatus = aQueueStatus;        // Pointer to the return status


  // Call MQCreateQueue to create the queue.
  WCHAR wszFormatNameBuffer[256];
  DWORD dwFormatNameBufferLength = 256;


  hr = MQCreateQueue(pSecurityDescriptor,         // Security descriptor
                     &QueueProps,                 // Address of queue property structure
                     wszFormatNameBuffer,         // Pointer to format name buffer
                     &dwFormatNameBufferLength);  // Pointer to receive the queue's format name length in Unicode characters not bytes.


  // Return the format name if the queue is created successfully.

  if (hr == MQ_OK || hr == MQ_INFORMATION_PROPERTY)
  {
    if (*pdwOutFormatNameLength >= dwFormatNameBufferLength)
    {
      wcsncpy_s(wszOutFormatName, *pdwOutFormatNameLength - 1, wszFormatNameBuffer, _TRUNCATE);

      wszOutFormatName[*pdwOutFormatNameLength - 1] = L'\0';
      *pdwOutFormatNameLength = dwFormatNameBufferLength;
    }
    else
    {
      wprintf(L"The queue was created, but its format name cannot be returned.\n");
    }
  }
  return hr;

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
std::cout<<"started!";
LPWSTR sam = L".\\myQueue";
LPWSTR out_name = L"Sampleoutput";
DWORD d1 = 60;
DWORD *dd = &d1;
HRESULT hs = CreateMSMQQueue(sam,pt,out_name,dd);
return 0;
}
```

I didn't change much of the code. When I run this code, I get an "**The application was unable to start correctly(0x0000142)**" error. By debugging I found out tat its due to an "**Memory access error**" but there is no hint as to where it occurs. Please help me out!

Is there any format for queue names? Or the output format name ?

Comment: Did your application start at all (i.e. did it print "started") ? Which line of code prints that message ?

Comment: You mis-quoted the error code, it ix 0xC0000142.  The DllMain() function in one of the DLLs your program uses crashed.  That's pretty bad, doesn't have anything to do with your code.  You need to look for an environmental cause, anti-malware for example.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Win32 Exception's Thrown checkbox might help to locate the troublemaker.

Comment: @HansPassant I turned on Win32 exceptions and I get this error! Still doesn't show where it occurs.. `First-chance exception at 0x000007fefd47940d in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: registry_access_error at memory location 0x0023eab0`

Comment: @MSalters No it doesn't even print "Started". As soon as it runs, it closes showing that exception.

Comment: Sounds fixable, use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see it access the registry.

Comment: @HansPassant U rock man!! Thanks for tat.. However it dint help directly but it made my day!! Thanks a lot..